# FBJS for complex applications

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbjs

I started looking at FBJS to build some complex application that **has to be within a tab** on a fan page.  Since my first option of using iframes are out till Facebook puts that functionality in, I have to resort to using the sanitized FBJS.

I was wondering if anyone has done really complicated apps using FBJS?  Besides DOM manipulations, how does it stack up against the usual JS?

I looked at the documentation online on the developers page, but all the samples there seem pretty basic.  For example, I would need to access ActiveXControls/plugins, generate iframe on the fly and then append content into the iframe, etc.  Does anyone think this would be doable in FBJS?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access custom ActiveXControls you won't be able to do it in FBJS. FBJS obscures global variables so you can't access them. I'm pretty sure that Facebook allows iframe applications in tabs on fan pages though. How are you adding the content?

Comment: The iframe implementation in fanpages is not yet supported.  It is part of the Q1 roadmap for 2011.  The content will be generated via Ajax calls.